# No logro hacer visualizar el código html de una tabla con bs4 en python

Tags: python, scraping

El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
url = "https://www.solotodo.cl/products/67620-fantech-pulse-cg71-rgb-black"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
tags = soup.find("table", {"class": "table table-sm mb-0"})
print(tags)
```

El resultado en tags es None, cuando en url la tabla existe bajo la misma clase.
He intentado bajo 100 formas distintas que tags me muestre algo del código, cualquier cosa pero nada me ha resultado.

Comment: Lo siento pero la página que descargas no contiene ningún elemento `table` y por eso `bs4` no los encuentra. Si crees que sí tiene esos elementos porque los has visto al "inspeccionar elemento" con el navegador, ocurre que lo que ves al inspeccionar elementos no es la página que has descargado, sino la que resulta después de que se haya ejecutado el javascript que venía con ella. Si quieres ver la página original, usa en cambio "Ver fuente de la página" y podrás comprobar que en él no viene ninguna `table`.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que lo que descarga el navegador es un "esqueleto" en el que rellenará posteriormente con más datos resultado de haber ejecutado el javascript y de haber hecho peticiones AJAX. Para hacer scraping de algo así, ya que Python no puede ejecutar el javascript, o bien depuras en el navegador paso a paso el código JS que se ejecuta hasta dar con la URL a la que se están haciendo las peticiones AJAX, para usar entonces esa URL con python, o bien deberás usar algo como selenium, que permite ejecutar la página en un navegador real (controlado desde python)